# How to Manage Service Provider in Silex

Tags: php, silex

We have to do this

```
$app->register(new Namespace\SomeServiceProvider());
```

to use Some Service Provider.

How if I need to use, let's say, 20 Provider,
I have to do `$app->register...` 20 times as well, is that fine ? is there a better way to register large provider in silex ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly fine, if you want to avoid writing `$app->register` that many times, you can define all your *Base Providers* in a config file and iterate them in your bootstrap.

You can use this [ConfigServiceProvider](https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider) to load a config file in various formats.